# How to stop other elements moving around when moving an element from relative layout in android studio?

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to make a basic application that adds two numbers, but each time I move something around, The entire layout gets messed up.
I added a separate View in the center to act as a reference point to counter this, but it is still getting very annoying.

Any idea on how to fix this? I am using Studio version 2.1

If not, is any other way to design the user interface without having to deal with relative layouts?

I have tried linear layouts but those only allow me to place my elements in fixed places which I cannot use in my app.

Please guide me.

Note: I apologize if this question is too simple. I am a newbie after all, do forgive me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using margin: http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/

also look you can align certain object in the xml code relative to eachother, have no link for that atm

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me alot. For those of you who are still curious to know, the answer is that arrange the elements as you wish. When you want to make it look better then use margins and padding to move that specific element. Very effective for small movements of around 50dp, you can also use it for larger movements.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed the function of `RelativeLayout` in Android Studio. If you are getting problems with dragging and dropping with `RelativeLayout` then you should try any other layout. eg. `ConstraintLayout`

2nd Solution:
Try adding new buttons instead of copying and pasting old ones.